# How do I select or create a category from my drop-down list?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am building an app with Java17 using Spring Boot. I am using data jpa, MVC and Thyemleaf.

The application that allows users to register their books on a reading list.
They can enter:
Book Title
Author
and I want to enter the category.
The category should be available to select from a drop-down list. If the category isn’t present then the user should be able to create one and it will be available on the drop-down list in future.

The error message I am receiving is:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required parameter 'categoryId' is not present.
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'categoryId' for method parameter type Integer is present but converted to null
```

I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to resolve the error but am getting nowhere.

Here are my relevant code snippets.

book-form.html

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/book/add}"
                        th:object="${book}" method="POST">

        <!--Adding hidden form field to handle the update-->
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

        <!-- Input fields for book information -->
        <input type="text" th:field="*{title}"
                class="form-control mb4 w-25" placeholder="Title">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{author.firstName}"
               class="form-control mb4 w-25" placeholder="Author First Name">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{author.lastName}"
               class="form-control mb4 w-25" placeholder="Author Last Name">

        <!-- Select dropdown for category -->
        <select th:field="*{category.id}" class="form-control mb4 w-25">
          <option value="">Select Category</option>
          <option th:each="category : ${categories}" th:value="${category.id}" th:text="${category.name}"></option>
          <option value="-1">Create New Category</option>
        </select>

        <!-- Hidden input fields for categoryId and categoryName -->
        <input type="hidden" name="categoryId" th:value="*{category.id}">
        <input type="text" name="categoryName" class="form-control mb4 w-25" placeholder="New Category Name">

        <hr>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Save</button>

      </form>
```

The two relevant methods from my controller

```
@GetMapping("registration")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model model){
        Book book = new Book();
        List<CategoryRecord> categories = readingListService.findAllCategories();
        model.addAttribute("book", book);
        model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
        return "books/book-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("add")
    public String addBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book, @RequestParam("categoryId") Integer categoryId, @RequestParam("categoryName") String categoryName) {
        if (categoryId != null && categoryId.equals(-1)) {
            // User selected option to create a new category
            Category newCategory = new Category(categoryName);
            Category savedCategory = readingListService.addCategory(newCategory);
            book.setCategory(savedCategory);
        }

        // Handle saving the book to the database
        readingListService.addBook(book);

        return "redirect:/book/list";
    }
```

The two entity classes that are referred to.

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
                            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}




import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Book> books;

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I think the issue lies within the HTML form ... the showFormForAdd method in the controller works fine and the addBook method breakpoints never get triggered. This leads me to believe that it is the way in which the categoryId is being binded.

If anyone has any suggestions on a better way to do this it's much appreciated.